Does this question have any chance to be salvaged?
The question.
I'm really not sure on how to add details or clarity, I've already added a couple of examples and ready to add more if necessary, but maybe the subject of the question itself is not allowed.

You did add nothing to the question. You need to Edit the question.

There are no edits to the question. Comments are routinely cleaned up on this site and don't stay up forever.

Alright, I actually edited the question. Thanks for the suggestion.
